# Javascript Web Audio API latency

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I want to make a Javascript program to process some audio from microphone. But when I make just a basic example, like get audio from microphone and play it back without any processing, just like this

```
source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

I get 200 milliseconds latency between input and output audio. I tried in Google Chrome and Firefox on 2 different PCs with Windows 7 and Windows 10 and it looks the same everywhere. I got this number (200ms) by recording and analysing audio with an external device, not just by my ears.

In official W3C specification [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#latency) they tell about 3-50 ms latency. 30-50 ms is what I need. I do not really need 3-5 ms.

I tried to play with latency parameter like this

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: {
    latency: 0.05,
    echoCancellation: false,
    mozNoiseSuppression: true,
    mozAutoGainControl: false
  }
});
```

but looks like it is ignored by Chrome and FireFox.

My full example is available here.

https://jsfiddle.net/xfq3ykp7/71/

Is it browser/hardware limitation or I am doing something wrong? Can anyone hear some latency with my example? Usually, it is easy to check it with hitting a table near a microphone. for 200 ms there is a noticeable delay between the hit and its sound.

I do not need complicated things like scheduled audio events etc which are needed for games or online musical instruments. I just need to decrease latency in my simple example from 200 ms to 50 ms or ideally to 20 ms.

UPDATE1:

I could make 70 ms on Windows 10 and 100 ms on Windows 7 in Firefox with that code change

```
var p = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: {
    latency: 0.02,
    echoCancellation: false,
    mozNoiseSuppression: false,
    mozAutoGainControl: false
  }
});
```

Thanks to firefox support (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1375466). But they tell that 30 ms should be possible. The question is still open "How to get 30 ms latency on Windows?" and "What is hardware requirements?".

Comment: Do you also experience it with other softwares than browsers ? Sounds like an hardware issue, and at least, I can't repro from your fiddle.

Comment: @Kaiido I did not try from another software. Can you recommend something, which I can trust and compare?
and what kind of OS/Browser and hardware do you have, when you cannot reproduce this problem?

Comment: I did try from FF and chrome on a mac notebook. For you to test, I don't know what softs you've got on your machine, but  guess you've got some built-in tools in your OS to do so, or Audacity can get access to your mic, Quicktime might be able too, or even skype might have a mic test feature.

Comment: @Kaiido I read on the internet that Mac is very good in this sense and latency is smaller on mac. I tried on windows with some cheap embedded soundcard. About software as I understand that Audacity is just recording/editing software. It cannot record and play immediately, as I want.

Comment: Hi Zlelik, 

i had a similar Problem in Linux when i tried to create a buffer an a button click for a sampling machine. On my laptop i had a latency of 500 ms. But i think it hadn't anything to do with the buffer itself it was more a browser and hardware issue. In my case the linux chrome version was buggy and on windows it did run allright. it could be something like this here. So please check if it runs the same speed on mac and linux than you would know it is somehow browser related.

Comment: @KilianHertel. Thanks for your help. I created Firefox bug. Maybe they will help, they are very responsive. Some useful information can be found here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1375466

I already managed to get it 100 ms, instead of 200. But Firefox support tells me that 30 ms is feasible.

Comment: This might be completely off-target, but I'll just mention for posterity, that if you have `channelCount` of the microphone set higher than 1 (default seems to be max the microphone supports), you will introduce extra delay. It's obvious in a way, but I've only been able to tweak it on FF, and not Chrome.

Comment: From my understanding what you are experiencing is pretty normal. Audio recorded from a mic passes through several hw and sw layers before being available to your code. Using BT mic, for example, can increase this delay. 
Software that needs more precision usually has a "calibrate" tool that try to find the delay and adjust everything else accordingly.

Comment: @Zlelik how do you measure the latency?

Comment: @Yukulélé I put my phone next to the computer and start recording the video. Then I hit something or make a single click sound, and it comes back from the computer with some delay due to latency. The phone records 2 hits/clicks in the video, one original and one delayed. Then I open this video in the editor and measure the distance between 2 hits/clicks.

Comment: I tried to write a synthesizer module with web audio api. This is from the software perspective perfectly possible, but the latency was even when tweaking everything always above 150ms which is very bad for audio processing. I think that the chrome engine and the FF engine are that bad. Linux was the worse. In Windows it was a bit faster, but not as good as expected. The internal processing of web audio api is fast enough it is just the gateway from external mic to browser so nothing you could influence yourself.